# if statements alternative with Java 8

Tags: java, if-statement, lambda, java-8

Have a function like this:

```
public void toDo(Req req){

    if(req.getSection().equals("A")) {
        return execA(req);
    }

    if(req.getSection().equals("B")) {
        return execB(req);
    }

    if(req.getSection().equals("N")) {
        return execN(req);
    }
}
```

How can I simplify it? The general idea, how to exclude **if** statements for the identification type of function - Strings - **A, B, N**. Any solutions with Java 8 like pattern matching with Scala?

Comment: Make your code object oriented and the whole method becomes `req.execute();`.

Comment: unless you declare a proper return type the only valid simplification would be to drop the entire method because otherwise you can not compile at all :)

Answer (score 8):

Can't you use just a simple switch?

```
switch (req.getSection()){
    case "A" : execA(req);  break;
    case "B" : execB(req);  break;
    case "N" : execN(req);  break;
    default:  break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Besides [the `switch` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37654945/2711488), which works for strings and `int` values, you can use a `Map`:

```
Map<String,Consumer<Req>> handlers;
{
    handlers.put("A", req -> execA(req));
    handlers.put("B", req -> execB(req));
    handlers.put("N", req -> execN(req));
}
Consumer<Req> defaultBehavior=req-> {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(req.getSection());
};
public void toDo(Req req) {
    handlers.getOrDefault(req.getSection(), defaultBehavior).accept(req);
}
```

Besides supporting other key types, it allows to assemble the map at runtime, e.g. using handlers provided by different, perhaps dynamically loaded, modules, etc.

Comment: Very interesting, and better yet, effectively opens the door to self-modifying code. Those were the days.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection and the array of methods you have on your class, you could apply a filter (if-replacement), mapping (to return value) and optionally defining a default value (orElse).

This approach might be good, if either the number of cases gets huge or dynamic. But for your particular case, I think it's overkill. Better stick to the switch-case solution.

```
public Optional<Object> toDo(Req req) {
    return Stream.of(this.getClass().getMethods())
                 .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("exec" + req.getSection()))
                 .map(this::invokeUnchecked).findFirst();
}

private Object invokeUnchecked(final Method m) {
    try {
        return m.invoke(this);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException| InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

In case you don't want to use an optional, you have to declare a default with `.findFirst().orElse(() -> ...)`